What Foreground Service Type is appropriate for a server socket to listen on incoming data
Android 14 requires that every Service has a foreground service type set.
What is the correct type for an App that needs to listen on a socket for incoming data and sometimes need to start an activity?

The service will not be able to start an activity from the background in general. Beyond that, the service type is not tied to a particular communications technology (socket). It is tied to the user/business reasons of why the service exists. dataSync, remoteMessaging, or specialUse are common ones, but others might be relevant depending on what you are doing.
